# Cytoscape.js Breathfirst layout

Tags: angular, networking, layout, graph-theory, cytoscape

My requirement is to create a `Breadth-First` graph with root node at the center.
When I use `center=true` option, Edges are getting overlap.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm.... breadthfirst have not a center property, may you refer to circle??

[image]

However, i think that for your purpose you can use concentric layout (https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts) specifying a root.

If you want to use the breadthfirst and the algorithm producing crossing edges you can

1. Open an issue to improve this aesthetic criterion
2. Try to generate a tweek from the algorithm result

you can change nodes coordinates with `node.position({ x: ...., y: .... })`

Comment: Yeah I meant circle, Thanks for the suggestion